# Python request package returns no data

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to read the JSON data returned from the URL below, however when I use the request package to read it, it returns no data.

When I run the below link on a browser, I can see the data. What might be the issue here?

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

https://apis.justwatch.com/content/titles/show_season/25282/locale/en_ID?language=en

Below is the code:

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import requests,json


url = 'https://apis.justwatch.com/content/titles/show_season/25282/locale/en_ID?language=en'
JW_titledetails = requests.get(url)
JW_details = json.loads(JW_titledetails.text)
print(JW_details)
```

This is the output I get:

```
{'items': None}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add headers to get the correct json.

Try this code:

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import requests,json

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'https://apis.justwatch.com/content/titles/show_season/25282/locale/en_ID?language=en'
JW_titledetails = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
JW_details = json.loads(JW_titledetails.text)
print(JW_details)
```

Comment: I should be pointed out that this behavior depends entirely on the server-side implementation of the API. They are probably applying some simple heuristic to return no data to (likely) automated requests.

Answer (score 0):

The API does not allow default headers passed by requests. As the API return json, use requests own `json`.

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

URI = 'https://apis.justwatch.com/content/titles/show_season/25282/locale/en_ID'
params = dict(language='en')
headers = {'User-Agent':'Pandas'}

r = requests.get(URI, params=params, headers=headers)
data = r.json()

print(data.keys())

# print(data)

# Now you can get data with pandas json_normalize
# example get credits 
# pandas.__version__ < 1.0.3
credits = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data, 'credits')

# pandas.__version__ >= 1.0.3
credits = pd.json_normalize(data, 'credits')
```

See [pandas.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) for more detailed usage and examples.